# ObjectIdFromHex invalid byte error on identical strings

Tags: mongodb, rest, go

I'm trying to implement a FindOne method in my Golang REST API. The trouble comes where i have to search by ID. I have to convert the ID into something readable by the database, so i use primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(id)
The problem is that this method throws an error :

```
2021/06/19 06:56:15 encoding/hex: invalid byte: U+000A
```

ONLY when i call it with the id that comes from my URL GET params.
I did two versions : one with hard-coded ID, and one with GET ID. See code below.

```
func Admin(id string) (bson.M, error) {
    coll, err := db.ConnectToCollection("admin")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var admin bson.M

    HardCoded := "60cb275c074ab46a1aeda45e"

    fmt.Println(HardCoded) // Just to be sure : the two strings seem identical
    fmt.Println(id) 

    objetId, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(id) // throws encoding error
    // objetId, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(HardCoded) // Doesnt throw encoding err

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var ctx = context.TODO()

    if err := coll.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": objetId}).Decode(&admin); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return admin, nil
}
```

Of course, you'll want to know where the param id comes from.
Here you go :

```
func GetAdmin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    admin, err := Admin(params["id"]) // Calling the Admin function above

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusUnauthorized)
    } else {
        JSON, err := json.Marshal(admin)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
        w.Write(JSON)
    }
}
```

Comment: Trim the line feed from the end of `id`: `id = strings.TrimSpace(id)`

Comment: HECC that done the trick congrats, post this as an answer if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trim the line feed from the end of id:

```
id = strings.TrimSpace(id)
```

Use the %q format verb when debugging issues like this.  The  line feed is clearly visible in this output:

```
fmt.Printf("%q\n", HardCoded) // prints "60cb275c074ab46a1aeda45e"
fmt.Printf("%q\n", id)        // prints "60cb275c074ab46a1aeda45e\n"
```